# How to extract point coordinates from VTK Points

Tags: vtk

I use a library that gives me at the end the vtkpoints. Now I would like to extract points
from them. But all the method available from VTKPoints require point id, which i do not know.
Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: The code is written in C++ and I am using VTK. By the way, I found the way, but it is not elegant. I am using the indexes: 0..NumberOfPoints as Ids in a loop, but probably this is not the secure way

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine which points to extract from your vtkPoints object? Depending on what you want to do there are a variety of options to do things efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't offer a definitive answer, since the [VTKPoints documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPoints.html) doesn't discuss the values of the point ids and I don't have any experience with this. However, all of the [examples](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/c2_vtk_e_5.html#c2_vtk_e_vtkPoints) I have seen just use integers in the range `[0..NumberOfPoints-1]` as the point ids, so it would seem that what you are doing is perfectly reasonable (note, however, that your comment `I am using the indexes: 0..NumberOfPoints` should be `0..NumberOfPoints-1`).

Comment: Ok, then I will use my solution and hope that nothing strange will happen. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The points are definitely just stored in a vector-like container with sequential indexing from 0 to GetNumberOfPoints()-1.